# run jQuery function by inline onClick and use function variable/reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to this, but I wrote this and thought it would work first time, but I get an 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: street' console error.

I get this error if I click on the 'Street' button.

It's quite basic but this is the first time I've made a function to use a var/ref from the onClick attribute.

Please see onClick markup...

```
<a href="#" title="View Supersport" onclick="bikeFilter(supersport)">Supersport</a>

<a href="#" title="View Street" onclick="bikeFilter(street)">Street</a>

<a href="#" title="View Cruiser" onclick="bikeFilter(cruiser)">Cruiser</a>

<a href="#" title="View Scooter" onclick="bikeFilter(scooter)">Scooter</a>      


<a href="#" title="Motocross" onclick="bikeFilter(motocross)">Motocross</a>

<a href="#" title="Enduro" onclick="bikeFilter(enduro)">Enduro</a>

<a href="#" title="Kids" onclick="bikeFilter(kids)">Kids</a>
```

then please see my function, which gets the ref error above...

**Also please note I am trying to use the onClick var/ref within my function so I can target specific elements relative to the button being clicked.**

```
bikeFilter = function (y) {

    $('.bike').fadeOut();

    scrollTo(186);

    $('.bike[data-group=' + y + ']').fadeIn();

    bikeSliderNav();

    bikeSlider();

    return false;

}
```

Any expert advice would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably wanna pass a **String** as input to your function and not the name of an undeclared and uninstantiated variable.

Try to use the single quotes to refer it as a String constant (you need single quotes since you are already using double quotes to tell your html tag the attribute value):

```
onclick="bikeFilter('scooter')"
```

Take a look [here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter2.html) to see the difference in data typing in js, and [here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html) for a quick start about functions.

Comment: Thanks for those links, I will take a look and learn. Nice one!

Comment: That tutorial is easy to follow but pretty much complete : )

Answer (score 1):

You should use them like :

```
onclick="bikeFilter('motocross')"
```

Don't forget to put ' around your parameters